# filtering array elements depending on sum condition pySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this

```
id  |  val  |  sum_needs_to_be
------------------------------
1   |   1   |  3
------------------------------
1   |   2   |  3
------------------------------
1   |   1   |  3
------------------------------
2   |   3   |  2
------------------------------
2   |   1   |  2
------------------------------
2   |   1   |  2
------------------------------
```

It has some ids, for each id, we get multiple records, together with one sum_needs_to_be which is the filter condition for the sum of vals should be. For example, id1 has goal of sum as 3, 1st and 2nd record's val, 1+2=3, then 1st and 2nd row is remained while 3rd record is ignored; id2 has goal of sum as 2, so 5th and 6th record is needed while 4th is ignored. Since for one id it might have multile solutions, only the first solution from top to bottom is needed(always take the smallest index record first if possible, if index 1,5 is valid while index 2,3,4 is valid also, choose 1,5 because 1 is smallest).

The output should be like

```
id  |  val  |  sum_needs_to_be
------------------------------
1   |   1   |  3
------------------------------
1   |   2   |  3
------------------------------
2   |   1   |  2
------------------------------
2   |   1   |  2
------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it confirmed that there is always a subset of rows whose sum will be exactly equal equal tocolumn - sum_needs_to_be ? Also is the order fix of the rows fixed. ? And finally what if  Val column has some rows with 0  how and what should be done

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  There is no guarantee for answer's existing so for the id that does not have an answer, the whole id should be ignored.  For the order of the row, yes if fixed because I already made a sort by some other columns.  For 0 val, it is guaranteed that all vals are positive integers must larger than 0.

Comment: Do you have the logic implement in python on a pandas dataframe , I can try to transform that function to spark